# Haskell writing a Filter for selfdefined List

Tags: list, haskell, filter

Heyho.

I am learning Haskell at University right now. There is a task I just can't wrap my head around. I don't understand why this won't compile. Hope someone can help me.
They gave us a self defined List and now we are supposed to create Filter that works with this list just like the Filter from the bib.
Here's the code:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a) deriving Show

list :: List Int
list = Cons (-3) (Cons 14 (Cons (-6) (Cons 7 (Cons 1 Nil))))

filterList :: (a -> Bool) -> List a -> List a
filterList f Nil = Nil
filterList f (Cons e l) | f e = e : (filterList f l)
                        | otherwise = (filterList f l)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your recursive call for the first case is wrong: You want to do `Cons e (filterList f l)` but you actually use `(:)` and not `Cons`. Reason for this being that `e : (filterList f l)` has type `[a]` but you actually want `List a`.

To solve this, just change

```
e : (filterList f l)
```

to

```
Cons e (filterList f l)
```

since you want it to return your the "non-standard" List type.

Comment: Your answer was fast and very well structured. Thank you for that. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`e : (filterList f l)` is not a `List a` but a `[a]`, use `Cons e (filterList f l)` instead.

(By the way, always post the error for this kind of questions. It may say nothing to you, but it often greatly helps us in answering.)